# Is it worth to use Oracle for a web application instead of PostgreSQL or MySQL?

Tags: mysql, oracle, postgresql

I'm starting a web application and I'm hesitating if it is worth to use Oracle in order to have a better performance / scalability. Thanks

Comment: Oracle and PostgreSQL provide richer functionality than MySQL, performance and or scalability concerns are not answerable without details/specifics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oracle requires significantly more infrastructure and specialized staff to be maintained than MySql for example. It offers, arguably, more in return. But since you are talking about scalability / performance, bear in mind that Wikipedia, Flicker, Facebook (and many of the most visited sites in the world today) run under MySQL...

So, put your focus on designing well your database instead of trying to find out which platform to use. Every single one of them has many strengths today, and are ready for production and demanding environments.

I, myself, would never ever even consider using Oracle from the start in a new Web Application. I would only jump to that more expensive RDBMS if really needed.

It can also pay off to use a ORM tool that will give you database independence, so changing the RDBMS will not be a big issue at all.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle can be very fast, but you have to spend millions of dollars for licences, hardware and dba-consulting hours. PostgreSQL is fast, has no licence costs and offers (almost) the same rich functionality as Oracle. PostgreSQL speed depends on your hardware and configuration as well, but you don't have to invest all your money right now to get started.

MySQL is populair, but has limited functionality and isn't as strict as you would expect from a DBMS.

Answer (score 1):

Write you application to be database generic.  That way you can move to whatever database works the best for a given installation.   That's relatively easy to do in most web environments these days.